# Trouble with the "initials" package [Solved]

Tags: packages, miktex

EDIT: Many thanks to Bernard for solving the issue. I needed to refresh the font map files.

I've been trying to experiment with using LaTeX for more than just math papers, and I thought I'd try using some of the more 'fun' text options available. For reference, I'm using MikTeX pdfLaTeX.

Specifically, I want to use the Acorn Initials (seen [here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/acorn/)). I installed the "initials" package from ctan and tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{initials}

\begin{document}

\input Acorn.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Acorn}{xl}{n}}

\initfamily Test

\end{document}
```

I then get the following error:

```
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.
.
.
.
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file Acorn): Font Acorn at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Where am I going wrong? I've tried updating everything through the MikTeX package manager, as well as uninstalling and re-installing the "initials" package, restarting my pc, etc.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you `Refresh font map files` (`Tasks` menu in MiKTeX console)?

Comment: No, but I'll give that a try! Edit: It worked! thank you so much! I had a feeling I was missing something basic.

Comment: It happens from time to time that MiKTeX forgets to refresh the type 1 fonts database. You can detect it when MiKTeX sends messages about trying to make .pk fonts (=bitmap fonts), which means it doesn't find the type 1 fonts.