# Metric (TFM) file not found when using the initials package in LaTeX

Tags: packages, texlive, ubuntu, ctan, drop-cap

I have installed the *initials* package from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/initials), using these [steps](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/how-can-i-manually-install-a-latex-package-debian-ubuntu-linux) on Ubuntu.

I want to use the `Acron` font, but when I run the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine, Acorn}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\Acornfamily}

\begin{document}
\lettrine{T}{ }est
\end{document}
```

I get the error `! Font U/Acorn/xl/n/10=Acorn at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.`
This error also occurs when I am not using lettrine:

```
\input Acorn.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Acorn}{xl}{n}}
\initfamily{Hello}
```

But the files `Acorn.tfm`, `Acorn.map`, `Acorn.pfb` and `Acorn.tex` are present in the installed directory as well as the `Acorn.fd`.

Reading [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485952/trouble-with-the-initials-package-solved), I realized that I may need to "Refresh font map files," but I am not using MikTeX.
I am using `texlive` and my editor is `texmaker`, on `Ubuntu 22.04`.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: probably you put the tfm into the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say I "solved" the problem, but I wanted to share this:
I just installed the `texlive-full` and it worked.